# How do I fix this Java notarization error?

Tags: java, install4j

I am trying to use the new notarization feature on Install4j to package and distribute a JavaFX app that is using JavaFX 14.0.1 and JDK 14.0.2. However, I keep getting the error message that the signature for `libjli.dylib` is invalid. Any ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: are you running in MacOS?

Comment: you may need to add entitlements in the form of a plist: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming install4j 8.0.8 will fix this issue. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.